# Запуск бота на локальной машине через ngrok и vpn

Tags: asp.net-core, telegram-bot, telegram, asp.net-web-api, vpn

Я хочу протестировать бота для телеграм на локальной машине.

Использую веб хуки и .net core 3.0. Для доступа к Telegram API использую Telegram.Bot. В России доступ к Telegram.API закблокирован, приходится использовать VPN.

Я запустил ngrok, но столкнулся с проблемой. Пост запросы от телеграма не приходят на локальную машину. Но гет запросы, которые делаю сам на адрес ngroka работают нормально.

Запускал ngrok командой: `ngrok http 54823 -host-header="localhost:54823"`, 54823 - порт, на котором запускается проект на iss, не тот, который для ssl.

Потом получал ссылку: `https://5bf38bda.ngrok.io`

И отпралял запросы: `get: https://5bf38bda.ngrok.io/api/message/update` и этот запрос активировал breakpoint внутри контроллера. Потом давал команду из клиента Telegram, то есть делал post запрос, ngrok перенаправляет ее, но не на локальную машину.

В веб интерфейсе ngrok я вижу следующее: [image: get request]
[image: post request]

Поле X-Forwarded-For - разное для этих запросов. Get - идёт на ip моего vpn, а Post - непонятно куда. Может быть проблема в этом? Я вообще могу таким образом использовать ngrok вместе с vpn? Или он будет стучаться на адрес vpn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не возьмусь утверждать, что я прав, но хочу поделиться опытом :) Сталкивался с такой же проблемой, что от телеграма запросы на сервер не приходят, и дело тут было не в веб-сервере, а в том, что провайдер их просто блокировал, т.е. блокируются запросы не только от клиентов на апи телеграма, но и в обратную сторону тоже. Смените грок на какой нибудь VDS и думаю, у вас всё заработает...
Более того, у телеграма, насколько я помню, есть ограничения по портам, можно исользовать только 443, 80, 88, or 8443, если ничего не изменилось...

[Вот тут довольно подробно разжёвано про веб-хуки](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#the-verbose-version)

Comment: Вы оказались совершенно правы. :) Я упустил тот факт, что есть ограничение по портам. До этого я деплоил на azure и heroku, все работало, но так нет возможно дебажить нормально. Сейчас поменял порт в `launchSettings.json` на 443, выполнил `ngrok http 443 -host-header="localhost:443"`, и всё заработало как надо, ответы пошли! Насчёт блокировки проблем не было, во время дебага использую vpn, на vds как уже сказал проблем действительно нет.